# Android recyclerview doesn't observe data immediately until I refresh or observe using handler after short time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

The recyclerview does not `Observe` the data until I refresh or use `Handler` and re `Observe` after short time (3 second at most). Otherwise it only displays a white screen(empty layout).

Note that I'm sure that both the recyclerview and the api works fine because if I put the handler, I make sure to show the data but only this way. And since `Handler` gives a very bad behavior, I want to get rid of it and figure what is the problem.

Code:

Api Interface:

```
interface ProductsApi {

    @GET("products")
    fun get_products_asc(
    ): Call<List<Product>>
    

    @GET("products?sort=desc")
    fun get_products_desc(
    ): Call<List<Product>>


}
```

View Model:

```
var new_collection_list : MutableLiveData<List<Product>>
init{
     new_collection_list = MutableLiveData()
}
fun get_new_collection_data() : MutableLiveData<List<Product>>{
         Log.d(TAG, "get_new_collection_data Home: Success Response")

        var call = api.get_products_desc()
         call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
                 if (response.body() != null){
                     new_collection_list.postValue(response.body()!!)
                     Log.d(TAG, "Home: Success Response")
                 }

                 else{
                     new_collection_list.postValue(null)
                     Log.d(TAG, "Home: Null Response")
                }
             }

             override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Home: Failure Response")
             }
         })

         return new_collection_list
    }
```

Fragment:

```
viewModel.get_new_collection_data().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            new_collections_adapter.submitList(it)
            new_collections_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

It's been days for me trying to solve this problem and will appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT: I have updated the code to match the answers still not working.

Code:

View Model:

```
var new_collection_list : MutableLiveData<List<Product>> 
init{
        new_collection_list = MutableLiveData()
        get_new_collection_data()
}
fun get_new_collection_data() {
         Log.d(TAG, "get_new_collection_data Home: Success Response")

        var call = api.get_products_desc()
         call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
                 if (response.body() != null){
                     new_collection_list.postValue(response.body()!!)
                     Log.d(TAG, "Home: Success Response")
                 }

                 else{
                     new_collection_list.postValue(null)
                     Log.d(TAG, "Home: Null Response")
                }
             }

             override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Home: Failure Response")
             }
         })

    }
```

Fragment:

```
viewModel.get_new_collection_data()
    
viewModel.new_collection_list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            new_collections_adapter.submitList(it)
            new_collections_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function, you can observe the live data directly like the code below. Since Live data is lifecycle aware it will trigger every time the code changes.
Also add a observe view model function with the code inside and call it once in the OnCreateView of the fragment once just for safety.

```
viewModel.new_collection_list.observe(
            this,
            Observer { getList->
                new_collection_list.let {
                    new_collections_adapter.submitList(it)
            new_collections_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Post Updated. Updated the code to match this answer still data is not loaded until I re ```Observe``` it again using ```Handler```.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your viewModel because you are calling API which goes into the background thread and allows the *return new_collection_list* to return immediately without waiting for the result.

**The solution is**: you can directly observe the liveData from your ViewModel whenever it gets updated

Step1. in ViewModel:-

```
fun get_new_collection_data(){
     Log.d(TAG, "get_new_collection_data Home: Success Response")

    var call = api.get_products_desc()
     call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
         override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
             if (response.body() != null){
                 new_collection_list.postValue(response.body()!!)
                 Log.d(TAG, "Home: Success Response")
             }

             else{
                 new_collection_list.postValue(null)
                 Log.d(TAG, "Home: Null Response")
            }
         }

         override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Home: Failure Response")
         }
     })

}
```

Step2. in fragment->

```
viewModel.get_new_collection_data()

viewModel.new_collection_list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        new_collections_adapter.submitList(it)
        new_collections_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
```

Comment: Post Updated. Updated the code to match this answer still data is not loaded until I re ```Observe``` it again using ```Handler```.